# FastAPI Endpoint Not Updating SQLite Database with Uploaded Data

Tags: python, sqlite, fastapi

I am working on a FastAPI application with an endpoint that is supposed to take an uploaded Excel file, process it, and update a SQLite database with the new data. However, I'm encountering an issue where the database does not seem to get updated with the uploaded data.

Here's the relevant part of my FastAPI endpoint code:

```
@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_file(name: str = Form(...), file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = await file.read()
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(contents))
    sheet = workbook.active
    rows = list(sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True))
    headers = rows[0]

    def convert_to_json_serializable(row):
        json_row = {}
        for key, value in zip(headers, row):
            if isinstance(value, datetime):
                json_row[key] = value.isoformat()
            else:
                json_row[key] = value
        return json_row

    data = [convert_to_json_serializable(row) for row in rows[1:]]  # Convert rows to list of dicts

    # Call TaskboardManager's uploadFile method with processed data
    db.uploadFile(name, data)
    return {"message": "Data uploaded successfully to Taskboard"}
```

And here's the corresponding `uploadFile` method in my `TaskboardManager` class, which is supposed to handle the database update:

```
    def uploadFile(self, name, file_path):
        # Check if the Taskboard exists
        if not self._taskboard_exists(name):
            raise Exception(f"Taskboard '{name}' does not exist.")

        # Load data from the spreadsheet or CSV file
        data = []
        headers = None  # To store column headers
        if isinstance(file_path, str):
            if file_path.endswith(".xlsx"):
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
                ws = wb.active
                headers = [
                    cell.value for cell in next(ws.iter_rows())
                ]  # Corrected line
                for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                    data.append(row)
            elif file_path.endswith(".csv"):
                with open(file_path, "r") as csv_file:
                    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                    headers = next(csv_reader)
                    for row in csv_reader:
                        data.append(row)
        elif isinstance(file_path, bytes):  # If file_path is bytes
            # Convert bytes to BytesIO for openpyxl
            inbytes = BytesIO(file_path)
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(inbytes)

            ws = wb.active
            headers = [cell.value for cell in next(
                ws.iter_rows())]  # Corrected line
            for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                data.append(row)
                
        elif isinstance(data, list) and all(isinstance(item, dict) for item in data):
            # New: Processing list of dictionaries
            if not data:
                return  # No data to process

            
            
            # Use headers from the first dictionary
            headers = list(data[0].keys())

            # Ensure that the Taskboard table has columns for all headers
            self._ensure_columns_exist(name, headers)

            with self.global_db:
                cursor = self.global_db.cursor()

                # Check for 'upload_id' column and process accordingly
                cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info('{}')".format(name))
                columns_info = cursor.fetchall()
                upload_id_exists = any(column[1] == "upload_id" for column in columns_info)

                if not upload_id_exists:
                    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE '{}' ADD COLUMN 'upload_id' INTEGER DEFAULT 0".format(name))
                    upload_id = 0
                else:
                    upload_id = cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(upload_id) FROM '{}'".format(name)).fetchone()[0]
                    upload_id = 0 if upload_id is None else (upload_id + 1)

                # Insert data
                for row_dict in data:
                    values = [upload_id] + [row_dict.get(header) for header in headers]
                    cursor.execute(
                        "INSERT INTO '{}' ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
                            name, ",".join(["'upload_id'"] + headers), ",".join(["?"] * (len(headers) + 1))
                        ),
                        values
                    )
                
        else:
            raise Exception("Unsupported data format for upload.")
```

I am expecting the endpoint to read the uploaded Excel file, convert its contents into a suitable format (in this case, a list of dictionaries), and then pass this data to the `uploadFile` method of the `TaskboardManager` class to update the SQLite database. However, after running this process, I don't see the expected changes in the database.

Am I missing something in the way I handle file uploads or database operations? I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You're setting `data = []` inside your `uploadFile` function, so there is no data to process. Use a debugger and set a breakpoint at the beginning of your function, and use it to step through each line and see where your assumptions are incorrect. Another good advice is to not let your `uploadFile` do three different things depending on its input; instead, have three different functions and call it with the type of content you have. And if you don't know, make a fourth function that checks it and then calls the correct function, instead of having everything in one large function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `uploadFile` method. Please revise it and let me know if you need any help!

Comment: Yes, actually I found the error, but thank you!